# Filtering an array with a deeply nested array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I filter an array with a deeply nested array? Given the following 2 arrays, I need the result to be an array with only the `rice cakes` and the `gluten-free-pizza` objects:

```
const foodsILike = ['gluten-free', 'carb-free', 'flavor-free'];
const foodsAvailable = [
  { name: 'pasta', tags: ['delicious', 'has carbs']}, 
  { name: 'gluten-free-pizza', tags: ['gluten-free']}, 
  { name: 'pizza', tags: ['delicious', 'best meal of the year']},
  { name: 'rice cakes', tags: ['flavor-free']}
]
```

I tried the following which just returns everything (the 4 objects):

```
var result = foodsAvailable.filter(function(food) {
  return foodsILike.filter(function(foodILike) {
    return foodILike === food;
  })
})

result
// Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Comment: Can you show example output ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for checking if foodsILike contains a tag.

```js
const foodsILike = ['gluten-free', 'carb-free', 'flavor-free'];
const foodsAvailable = [{ name: 'pasta', tags: ['delicious', 'has carbs'] }, { name: 'gluten-free-pizza', tags: ['gluten-free'] }, { name: 'pizza', tags: ['delicious', 'best meal of the year'] }, { name: 'rice cakes', tags: ['flavor-free'] }]

var result = foodsAvailable.filter(function(food) {
    return food.tags.some(function(tag) {
        return foodsILike.includes(tag);
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what's a more performant way to do this? If you were deeply nested with large arrays this could get computationally expensive.

Comment: @zero_cool, it depends on the structure and the wanted result, like all nodes to the found item or just the item of the nested structure. maybe it could be faseter with an object or map for `foodsILike`. for speeding, the array methods should be avoided if speed really matters.

Comment: @NinaScholz Could you take a look at a question I've posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663557/most-performant-way-to-sort-a-deeply-nested-array-of-objects-by-another-deeply-n
This is related to my question above

Comment: This is great! For anyone finding this later and wanting it reformatted in ES6 like I did, it would be: ```const result = foodsAvailable.filter(food => food.tags.some(tag => foodsILike.includes(tag));```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `length` check on your inner filter and you aren't checking the tags array for the value in that inner filter

```js
const foodsILike = ['gluten-free', 'carb-free', 'flavor-free'];
const foodsAvailable = [
  { name: 'pasta', tags: ['delicious', 'has carbs']}, 
  { name: 'gluten-free-pizza', tags: ['gluten-free']}, 
  { name: 'pizza', tags: ['delicious', 'best meal of the year']},
  { name: 'rice cakes', tags: ['flavor-free']}
]

var result = foodsAvailable.filter(function(food) {
  return foodsILike.filter(function(foodILike) {
    // is value in tags array?
    return food.tags.indexOf(foodILike) >-1;
  }).length;// length acts as boolean, any length greater than zero is truthy
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.reduce` to reduce your array into desired structure, by checking for the condition i.e. `foodsILike` contains the `tag` or not.

The benefit of using `array.reduce` is that you can modify the structure if you want in the `reduce` loop itself.

```js
const foodsILike = ['gluten-free', 'carb-free', 'flavor-free'];
const foodsAvailable = [
  { name: 'pasta', tags: ['delicious', 'has carbs']}, 
  { name: 'gluten-free-pizza', tags: ['gluten-free']}, 
  { name: 'pizza', tags: ['delicious', 'best meal of the year']},
  { name: 'rice cakes', tags: ['flavor-free']}
];

let foods = foodsAvailable.reduce((foods, food) => {
  if(foodsILike.some(f => food.tags.indexOf(f) !== -1)) {
    foods.push(food);
  }
  return foods;
},[]);

console.log(foods);
```