# JavaScript Deeply Nested Array filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a somehow functional "deeply" nested array filtering functionality. This functionality displays car, which has a color "RED" assigned to them. However the cars, which "pass" the filter is the car, which only has 1 color assigned. 
How can ensure that arrays within arrays are being checked by the criteria? Would I require creating a loop within loop? The desired outcome would be that if criteria is set to "RED" it will also display the BMW and SUZUKI as these cars also have this color. 
Any help, suggestions or further links to other posts to achieve the desired outcome would be truly appreciated as I was not able to find anything very useful on my own. The post, which has been most useful has been this one - [Filtering an array with a deeply nested array in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482466/filtering-an-array-with-a-deeply-nested-array-in-js) 
 Below I have attached the code snippet of my current code.

```js
const myCars = [
    { name: "BMW",colour: ["White","Red","Black"] },
    { name: "AUDI",colour: ["Yellow","Silver"] },
    { name: "VW",colour: ["Purple","Gold"] },
    { name: "NISSAN",colour: ["White","Black"] },
    { name: "SUZUKI",colour: ["Red"] }, 
];

for (x in myCars) {
  var keys = Object.keys(myCars[x])

  var carSpec = myCars.filter(function(fltr) {
    return (fltr.colour == "Red");

  });
  document.getElementById("show1").innerHTML += carSpec[x].name + " " + "has these colours - " + carSpec[x].colour + "<hr />";
}
```

```html
<p>Car List.</p>

<p id="show"></p>
<p id="show1"></p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `filter` by an `includes` test over the `colour` array:

```js
const myCars = [
    { name: "BMW",colour: ["White","Red","Black"] },
    { name: "AUDI",colour: ["Yellow","Silver"] },
    { name: "VW",colour: ["Purple","Gold"] },
    { name: "NISSAN",colour: ["White","Black"] },
    { name: "SUZUKI",colour: ["Red"] }, 
];
const show1 = document.getElementById("show1");
myCars
  .filter(({ colour }) => colour.includes('Red'))
  .forEach(({ name, colour }) => {
    show1.innerHTML += name + " " + "has these colours - " + colour + "<hr />";
  });
```

```html
<p>Car List.</p>

<p id="show"></p>
<p id="show1"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to get an array of cars which have are available in red , then use `forEach` to loop over it and display the text.

`join` will join all the contents of an array by the delimiter

```js
const myCars = [{
    name: "BMW",
    colour: ["White", "Red", "Black"]
  },
  {
    name: "AUDI",
    colour: ["Yellow", "Silver"]
  },
  {
    name: "VW",
    colour: ["Purple", "Gold"]
  },
  {
    name: "NISSAN",
    colour: ["White", "Black"]
  },
  {
    name: "SUZUKI",
    colour: ["Red"]
  },

];


let hasRed = myCars.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (curr.colour.indexOf('Red') !== -1) {
    acc.push(curr)
  }
  return acc;

}, []).forEach((item) => {
  document.getElementById("show1").innerHTML += item.name + " " + "has these colours - " + item.colour.join(',') + "<hr />";
})
```

```html
<p>Car List.</p>

<p id="show"></p>
<p id="show1"></p>
```