# JavaScript Deeply nested array filtering methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I am experimenting with deeply nested array filtering with JavaScript. I have created a solution which works but would anyone be able to demonstrate any alternative methods (faster or more efficient) how to accomplish the same task provided with the code below. 
`function carReturn()
{
return myCars.filter(myCars => myCars.colour.includes("Red"));
}`
 The scenario and the purpose of the code is to filter out the cars, which have color "Red" attached to them. 
Below I have attached the full demonstration of the code. 
 Thanks for any help or recommendations.

```html
<p>Car List.</p>

<p id="show"></p>
<p id="show1"></p>

<script>
const myCars = [
    { name: "BMW",colour: ["White","Red","Black"] },
    { name: "AUDI",colour: ["Yellow","Silver"] },
    { name: "VW",colour: ["Purple","Gold"] },
    { name: "NISSAN",colour: ["White","Black"] },
    { name: "SUZUKI",colour: ["Red"] },
    { name: "Lada",colour: ["Gray","Red"] },

];

function carReturn()
{
return myCars.filter(myCars => myCars.colour.includes("Red"));
}
var jol = carReturn();


document.getElementById("show").innerHTML += jol;

console.log(carReturn('Red'));

</script>
```

**PS the innerHTML does not work but the functionality works within console.** 
 The posts used for reference has been: 
[JavaScript filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51941263/javascript-filtering) 
 [Filtering an array with a deeply nested array in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482466/filtering-an-array-with-a-deeply-nested-array-in-js)

Comment: Using a simple for loop will be way faster, but for small numbers of items, completely unnoticeable.

Comment: @luca I doubt even that.